# Can someone walk me through this laravel code

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel..currently learning to use the auth middleware. can someone walk me through the code..with emphasis on this line

```
 @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                            </li>
                        @endif
```

the rest of the code under app.blade.php code under layout folder is below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Welcome to laravel ..  Learning laravel will make you learn a lot of the modern web development techniques as you go through it.

about the code it's a check that determines whether your app's router has a route named register or not ..

by default this route will not be register .. but after you run this command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

laravel will register it for you by adding `Auth::routes()` to routes/web.php

Comment: Thank you.. Why doesn't it check for login route too?..why does it Check for only register route and what does @guest mean?

Comment: @Morpheus I think it checks login too in order to display the login anchor .. I’m far away from my laptop now .. will check it for you after getting to it

Comment: Ummm as I saw they use ether has login or register because Auth::routes() register both of them .